# Allow html comments with kses

Tags: wp-kses

How do I allow HTML comments (`<!-- HTML Comment -->`) when outptutting with `wp_kses_post`?

My current allow function is as follows:

```
function custom_wpkses_post_tags( $tags, $context ) {

    $allowed_atts = array(
        'align'      => true,
        'class'      => true,
        'type'       => true,
        'id'         => true,
        'dir'        => true,
        'lang'       => true,
        'style'      => true,
        'xml:lang'   => true,
        'src'        => true,
        'alt'        => true,
        'href'       => true,
        'rel'        => true,
        'rev'        => true,
        'target'     => true,
        'novalidate' => true,
        'type'       => true,
        'value'      => true,
        'name'       => true,
        'tabindex'   => true,
        'action'     => true,
        'method'     => true,
        'for'        => true,
        'width'      => true,
        'height'     => true,
        'data'       => true,
        'data-*'     => true,
        'title'      => true,
        'for'        => true
    );

    if ( 'post' === $context ) {
        $tags['form']     = $allowed_atts;
        $tags['label']    = $allowed_atts;
        $tags['select']   = $allowed_atts;
        $tags['option']   = $allowed_atts;
        $tags['input']    = $allowed_atts;
        $tags['textarea'] = $allowed_atts;
        $tags['iframe']   = $allowed_atts;
        $tags['script']   = $allowed_atts;
        $tags['style']    = $allowed_atts;
        $tags['strong']   = $allowed_atts;
        $tags['small']    = $allowed_atts;
        $tags['table']    = $allowed_atts;
        $tags['span']     = $allowed_atts;
        $tags['abbr']     = $allowed_atts;
        $tags['code']     = $allowed_atts;
        $tags['pre']      = $allowed_atts;
        $tags['div']      = $allowed_atts;
        $tags['img']      = $allowed_atts;
        $tags['h1']       = $allowed_atts;
        $tags['h2']       = $allowed_atts;
        $tags['h3']       = $allowed_atts;
        $tags['h4']       = $allowed_atts;
        $tags['h5']       = $allowed_atts;
        $tags['h6']       = $allowed_atts;
        $tags['ol']       = $allowed_atts;
        $tags['ul']       = $allowed_atts;
        $tags['li']       = $allowed_atts;
        $tags['em']       = $allowed_atts;
        $tags['hr']       = $allowed_atts;
        $tags['br']       = $allowed_atts;
        $tags['tr']       = $allowed_atts;
        $tags['td']       = $allowed_atts;
        $tags['p']        = $allowed_atts;
        $tags['a']        = $allowed_atts;
        $tags['b']        = $allowed_atts;
        $tags['i']        = $allowed_atts;
    }

    return $tags;

}
```

Comment: what's the context for allowing this? what problem does it solve? And where is the function going to be used?

Comment: There's a large amount of content being prepared via output buffering. The comments are strictly internal, but it'd be nice to not have to delete them for our bundled version. The problem is that codesniffer is asking for the returned output to be escaped. (Sidenote: everything inside the OB is already escaped)

Comment: ah you're early escaping :( you're supposed to escape as late as you possibly can, storing everything up in a variable or output buffer increases the time to first byte and has performance consequences, as well as security consequences. Putting aside your HTML comments, you should still late escape and abandon the output buffers where possible, `kses` isn't really escaping, it's a sanitising function, and will never be as effective as `esc_html`/`esc_attr`/etc, and can't protect you against injection attacks, it just limits them to whitelisted tags (that giant spam header still makes it)

Comment: I'd also be extremely concerned by filtering to change the kses tags, the function in this question is incredibly insecure as it allows iframes and scripts. With these the function is harmful to your sites security, and should not be used.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, @TomJNowell ! The hope is to eventually move away from ob, but for now, the plugin is already built (not by me) with ob so the hope is to address the escaping issues immediately and fix the overall build later. Keeping in mind what you said about late escaping, what is the best way to escape the overall OB instead of escaping each variable along the way? I misunderstood kses and thought that was escaping.. and have now learned it's just not great for this situation even if it was 

Comment: there is no reliable secure way to escape an output buffer, the most you can hope for is mitigation by stripping out unwanted tags, but your kses filter allows everything dangerous through anyway, so there would be no difference. A call to `wp_kses(` with that array would be equivalent although it would be a cleaner implementation, but it would bring no security benefits. You should still escape when generating the HTML, but unless you output immediatley there is no working around this. Unless you fix the root problem a PHPCS ignore is the only feasible mitigation, albeit a lacklustre one

Comment: unless your output buffer should be plaintext that never has HTML in it, in which case `esc_html` or stripping all tags will do the job